# Content Porter Export and Import to new Tridion Instance

Tags: content-porter

We have 2 Tridion instance, one is at amazon aws and another in separate server. Now, we have decided to create a new amazon aws and move the content to the new tridion instance. So, i started to content porter the items and facing issue While exporting items. I checked the publication size in webdav connection and it is 7.5 gb size.

I am thinking to port using content porter core service API, will that help to resolve the issue?. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches you might consider

- Clone the database from Server A to Server B. Then change the few environment specific items (e.g. Publication Targets) and remove / delete anything you did not want to Port
- Make several smaller Content Ports (via API or manually), normally ordered by type lowest to highest (e.g. Folders & Structure Groups, then Schemas, then Components, then Templates, then Pages etc..)

Content Porter is not designed to move entire implementations (with lots of content and images) from one instance to another. It is a deployment tool, for Templates, TBBs, Schemas etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with content porter, it is very helpful tool for small porting however not a good tool for very large data like yours.

Since your one instance is Amazon AWS, I assume you are on web 8.

For your there are two alternatives:

> 1. If you are on web 8 with web 8 type publishing with topology manager then database clone is the fastest approach. You can clone the
>      database and point to that database from your CM environment.
> 2. Leverage webdav: Connect to both webdav paths, from source webdav copy the files to file system and then copy files from file system to
>      destination webdav.

However, webdav is not a good option for component with metadata, pages and categories and keywords et. as those are not exposed so very limited use possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, Content Porter is not intended for database migration purposes, but I would say that WebDAV is much less suited  than Content Porter; not all item types are exposed through WebDAV and for Components the metadata is not exposed.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I missed that point, updated my answer with those details.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the two suggestions that Chris has made in his answer. I guess that the approach depends on whether you need to delete any content (and if so, then how much!) following a database clone.

Another alternative, if you want to go down the Content Porting route (and be able to 'cherry pick' the content to move) would be to use the [Import Export Service](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C1B075E6-7C62-450E-AFB5-77BB5C9C599F).

The main advantage of using the Import Export Service is that you can control the logic of which items to transfer and, being scripted, it will allow you to run and test the transfer faster and more efficiently than having to use the Content Porter Tool.